# Return pressed key without enter for confirmation

Tags: c, windows, keypress

I've searched for a while to find a function in Windows systems to use in C programming, to determine which key was pressed, without requiring the 'enter' key for confirmation.

I've found `kbhit()`, but this only returns positive on key press, and 0 while no key-press. I'd like the same behavior on a function, but returning my key's ASCII code.

The reason is that I want to build some controls, on a console-based game, where I need arrows to navigate the player.  'A' would move my point left, 'D' right.

At this moment, I need to press 'a' and 'enter,' 'd' and 'enter,' with the simple `scanf("%c")`, and would be nice if the console would react only if pressing a letter instead of a+enter on every movement.

Answer (score 4):

Look at this:

```
char ch;
ch = getch();
if(ch == 's') printf("you pressed s \n");
```

Answer (score 3):

From the sound of things you want something like this:

```
#include <conio.h>

int ch;

if (kbhit())
    ch = getch();
```

`getch()` blocks waiting for input, but it will read a single keystroke without buffering, so it doesn't wait for you to press the enter key.

Comment: actually, if (!kbhit()),   but yes.  Never knew how getch works. Always used it to stop console exiting and nothing more. Thank you.